# Both shift keys not working

Tags: keyboard, windows-11

Asking for a fried, who does not have an S.E account.

- Both shift-keys stopped working "a few weeks ago"
- "shortly after upgrade to Windows 11", but no recollection if they ever worked with Windows 11, even for a short time
- sticky keys is turned off completely
- keyboard driver is up to date
- uninstalling keyboard and rebooting to detect it did not help
- an external USB keyboard works

which leaves me thinking "hardware problem", except

- both shift keys stopped working at the same time
- all other keys work fine
- nothing has been spilled on it
- ***BUT*** ...
- there ***is*** a cat - who likes walking over the keyboard

any ideas?

Comment: Replace keyboard & cat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since *both* Shift keys are dead, and yet an external USB keyboard works as expected,  the cause is not in the key *mechanism*, but in an electrical connection or controller inside the keyboard. Replacement keyboards are often inexpensive and easy to replace.

It's likely *not* cat fur that did that: cats on occasion, will scent-mark  objects. (A friend had an electrical outlet *and* an electric stove controller fried, at different times, from such repeated "leakage".) Look into a waterproof keyboard or cover.

Comment: He likes to walk across the keyboard, often rotating the display :-)  I will look into the cost of a replacement keyboard. Alas, teh laptop is no longer under warranty

Comment: The last keyboard I replaced was not OEM, cost <US$10, and required just removal and replacement of a single bolt... and it works well. Hopefully, yours will be as easy.

Answer (score 1):

> an external USB keyboard works  .....    there is a cat - who likes
> walking over the keyboard

At this point, the (broken) keyboard needs to be replaced. It is impractical (98%) to fix keyboards. Just replace.