# My cat walked on my keybord (dell)

Tags: hotkeys

My cat walked on my keyboard and now the f keys are crazy, i mean, once they used to adjust brightness and sound volume, but now f3 is opening the search tab, f11 is fullscreen mode, f12 open dev tools, and f1 is help. I know those are the classic functions of those keys, but I can't make them work as the laptop intended no matter what!
I tried:

- deleting the keyboard drives and reinstalling them
- fn + esc
- fn + every other key on the keyboard(lol)
  Please help!

Comment: Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: How heavy was this cat? Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: If System Restore is enabled, restore Windows to its state as before the cat event.

Comment: Does your keyboard have any button for the Fn Lock feature to switch between standard function keys and the media keys?

Comment: Which laptop model are we talking about? https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-unlock-the-dell-fn-key Try Fn + Numlock

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1735829/both-shift-keys-not-working ; commiserate together?

Comment: @John - Before you complain about the drive by downvotes, and no one fixing your answer, you didn’t issue an edit to your answer before deleting it

Comment: 4 downvotes in well under 4 minutes.  No time . I think you completely missed my point.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you turned on Fn lock. Press the Fn lock key, or if that does not work press Fn + Escape to fix it.

Comment: Yes.. and that you have focus on the browser.